# Convert timestamp in HH:TT:SS format to seconds

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, timedelta, python-datetime

I'm trying to create a code on py2.7 to calculate the time difference for the time format of HH:MM:SS and convert it to seconds.

Turns out I had to call seconds like so:

```
    timediff = a-b
    seconds = timediff.total_seconds() #This was the simple solution
```

The error I did receive was:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Thanks to Ajay and J.F. Sebastian for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `totalseconds()` from `datetime.timedelta`

```
In [4]: t = time.strptime('00:01:25','%H:%M:%S')

In [5]: datetime.timedelta(hours=t.tm_hour,minutes=t.tm_min,seconds=t.tm_sec).total_seconds()
Out[5]: 85.0
```

For your example:

```
In [14]: t1='00:01:25'

In [15]: t2='00:01:10'
In [17]: t1 = time.strptime(t1,'%H:%M:%S')

In [18]: t2 = time.strptime(t2,'%H:%M:%S')
In [22]: datetime.timedelta(hours=t1.tm_hour,minutes=t1.tm_min,seconds=t1.tm_sec).total_seconds()-datetime.timedelta(hours=t2.tm_hour,minutes=t2.tm_min,seconds=t2.tm_sec).total_seconds()
Out[22]: 15.0
```

Comment: but in the same format `'HH:MM:SS'` and check which is greater or take an absolute while taking the difference
or alternatively `print sum(int(x) * 60 ** i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(t.split(":"))))`

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'split'

You almost there. `timediff` in your code is `datetime.timedelta`. To get seconds, just call `seconds = timediff.total_seconds()`.